# Clear ghci screen of haskell-mode

Tags: haskell-mode

I want to clear the `ghci` screen of the `haskell-mode`,

I used `erase-buffer` in emacs shell, and I works, but when I do so with `ghci` inside emacs, This message appears:

```
Text is read-only
```

Comment: did you try using `comint-clear-buffer` bound to `C-c M-o` ? this will work for all comint based interactive processes.

Comment: Error: "Wrong type argument: processp, nil"

Comment: I've found a solution.
(C-c C-k) == M-x  haskell-interactive-mode-clear

Comment: Ah yes, that's the same shortcut I use for `intero` repl :) I forgot it worked for haskell interactive mode as well.

Comment: @T.Magdy: please post your solution and accept it so that we can mark this post as answered.

Comment: Sure, I will @Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `haskell-mode`, `C-c C-l` calls `haskell-process-load-or-reload`, and you go into a sub-mode called `haskell-cabal-mode-map`.

In that mode there is a command `haskell-interactive-mode-clear` to clear the `ghci` buffer. (`erase-buffer` does not work, because the buffer is read-only so you cannot erase it)

So You can map `haskell-interactive-mode-clear` like that:

`(eval-after-load 'haskell-cabal '(progn
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'haskell-interactive-mode-clear)`